# django mysql connector - is allowing >1 entry for per specifc field in django

Tags: python, mysql

ive written some code to parse a website, and input it into a mysql db.

The problem is I am getting a lot of duplicates per `FKToTech_id` like:

```
id   | ref              | FKToTech_id              |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
|  1 | website.com/path |                        1 |
|  2 | website.com/path |                        1 |
|  3 | website.com/path |                        1
```

What Im looking for is instead to have (1) row in this database, based on if `ref` has been entered already for `FKToTech_id` and not have multiple of the same row like:

```
id   | ref              | FKToTech_id              |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
|  1 | website.com/path |                        1 |
```

How can I modify my code below to just python `pass` if the above is True (`==1 ref with same FKToTech_id`?

```
   for i in elms:
        allcves = {cursor.execute("INSERT INTO TechBooks (ref, FKToTech_id) VALUES (%s, %s) ", (i.attrs["href"], row[1])) for row in cves}
        mydb.commit()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make `ref` a unique column, then use `INSERT IGNORE` to skip the insert if it would cause a duplicate key error.

```
ALTER TABLE TechBooks ADD UNIQUE INDEX (ref);
```

```
for i in elms:
    cursor.executemany("INSERT IGNORE INTO TechBooks (ref, FKToTech_id) VALUES (%s, %s) ", [(i.attrs["href"], row[1]) for row in cves])
    mydb.commit()
```

I'm not sure what your intent was by assigning the results of `cursor.execute()` to `allcves`. `cursor.execute()` doesn't return a value unless you use `multi=True`. I've replaced the useless set comprehension with use of `cursor.executemany()` to insert many rows at once.